# Racket AND logical statement or nested if's with struct

Tags: struct, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to just make a simple Racket block of code with an AND or just nested-if logical statement. This is supposed to just specify if variable hours is above 0 and below 24 hours and minutes is above 0 and below 60 minutes within a struct called 24hourClock, if not it should type an else error statement for hours individually or minutes individually. If you can, just let me know if there's a minor syntax error, I'm just now learning struct and Racket in general. Thanks.

```
;Attempt 1
(struct 24HourClock (hours minutes)
  #:transparent
  #:guard     (if (number? hours)
                  (error name "24HourClock: Hours must between 0 and 23:24.")
                  (if (number? minutes)
                     (error name "24HourClock: Minutes must between 0 and 59:60.")                
                (values x y))))            

;Attempt 2                 
(struct 24HourClock5 (hours minutes)
 #:guard (lambda (hours minutes error_name)
           (if (not (and (number? hours) (number? minutes)))
               (error error_name "Both fields hours and minutes must be between 0:24 and 0:60")
               (values hours minutes))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guard argument must be a *procedure*, as in your second attempt.
It is probably a good idea to define it outside the struct definition, since it is not exactly tiny.
Something like this, perhaps:

```
(define (valid-hours h)
  (and (>= h 0) (< h 24)))

(define (valid-minutes m)
  (and (>= m 0) (< m 60)))

(define (valid-time h m name)
  (cond
    [(not (valid-hours h)) (error name "Bad hours")]
    [(not (valid-minutes m)) (error name "Bad minutes")]
    [else (values h m)]))

(struct 24HourClock (hours minutes)
  #:transparent
  #:guard valid-time)
```